# pdftitle and such ignored if specified after \maketitle with report and book classes, not with article class

Tags: hyperref, pdf, titles

The following MWE shows that, with `report` (and `book`) class, PDF information entries such as `pdftitle` specified thanks to `\hypersetup` are ignored if they are inserted after `\maketitle` (and not ignored if inserted before `\maketitle`).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\maketitle
\hypersetup{%
  pdftitle=A PDF Ttitle,
  pdfauthor=A PDF Author,
  pdfsubject=A PDF Subject,
  pdfcreator=A PDF Creator,
  pdfproducer=A PDF Producer,
  pdfkeywords=A PDF Keyword%
}%
\end{document}
```

It wouldn't be that surprising if it would be the case with all standard classes but, with `article` class, such PDF information entries are not ignored, no matter they are inserted before or after `\maketitle`.

Is there a way to make such entries not ignored with `report` and `book` class, even if inserted after `\maketitle`?

Comment: @ChristianH.: There is no cause, because there is no bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information entries are written when the first page is shipped out. The `report` class uses the `titlepage` environment in `\maketitle`, which puts the title on the page and starts a new page.

The best is to set the entries earlier, e.g. in the preamble.

Comment: That's strange that information entries need the first page to shipped out to be written. Is there any technical reason for this? Would it be possible to make them written `\AtEndDocument` instead, in order to avoid the current limitation? Setting these entries in the preamble could be annoying for French users as some characters are made active only at `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: Limitation of TeX: `\special` does not add anything to the DVI output *after* the last page.

Comment: Well, what about writing them just before the last page is shipped out? And what about with PDFTeX?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: TeX does not know, when it ships out a page that this page would be the last page. Therefore at least two LaTeX runs are needed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: pdfTeX does support it directly via a primitive `\pdfcatalog`. It does not depend on `\special`.

Comment: When you say that at least two LaTeX runs are needed, do you mean it would be possible to circumvent the current limitation (PDF information entries ignored with `report` and `book` class, if inserted after `\maketitle`)?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: Yes, but I do not see any need for a complicate circumvention.

Comment: PDF informations entry such as `/Keywords` or `/Subject` may be hidden in `\keywords` or `\subject` macros (provided by a class or a package), that would not only add the corresponding data in the PDF metadata but also print it in the document. As already said, inserting these macros in the preamble could be problematic for French users and, if this data is not planned to be printed in the title, but rather in subsequent pages, it would not be very natural to insert these macros before `\maketitle`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: `\shorthandoff` is also available for French users. Also the entries can be given after `\begin{document}`, but before the first page is shipped out. Also `\title`, `\author`, `\date` are given before `\maketitle`.

Comment: I am aware about `\shorthandon/off` but I would like to spare such boring and technical details to users of a class (for PhD theses, among others) I'm currently working on. About `\title`, `\author`, `\date` given before `\maketitle`, this is natural as they will appear in the title but keywords and subject may appear later.