# Why \shorthandon and \shorthandoff cannot be embedded in other macros?

Tags: macros, babel, shorthands

Surrounding `\title` macro with `\shorthandon{;:!?}` and `\shorthandoff{;:!?}` gives the expected result with `babel`'s `french` language (space added before the '?', '!', ':' and ';'):

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
%
\shorthandon{;:!?}%
\title{La crise? Quelle crise?}
\shorthandoff{;:!?}%
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't work if `\shorthandon` and `\shorthandoff` are embedded in (a redefinition of) the `\title` macro:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
%
\let\titleORI\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{%
  \shorthandon{;:!?}%
  \titleORI{#1}%
  \shorthandoff{;:!?}%
}
%
\title{La crise? Quelle crise?}
\author{Un auteur? Deux auteurs!}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

What is the reason of this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: catcode changes always have the same restriction, same as `\verb` not working in a macro argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saying `\shorthandon{?}` makes `?` an active character. So, when the argument to `\title` is absorbed, in the first example, it is active and, at `\maketitle`, LaTeX will use the current definition for it, which happens to be the one defined by `babel-french`.

On the contrary, in the second case the `\shorthandon` command is executed when the argument to `\title` has already been absorbed, so `?` is not active and such it will remain forever (in the replacement text of `\@title`, which is the macro where `\title` stores the title).

You have to delay reading the argument after `\shorthandon` has been executed.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\let\ORItitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}{%
  \shorthandon{;:!?}%
  \titlewithshorthand
}
\newcommand{\titlewithshorthand}[1]{%
  \ORItitle{#1}%
  \shorthandoff{;:!?}%
}

\title{La crise? Quelle crise?}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But I'd simply place `\title` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Placing `\title` after `\begin{document}`, and before `\maketitle`, is natural (and in any case necessary) as the corresponding argument will appear in the 'made' title. But, back to my other question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166878/18401, for other macros from a custom class, such as `\keywords`, it is not natural to impose its insertion before `\maketitle`. Hence, I would prefer to store all these 'document properties' macros (`\title`, `\keywords`, etc.) in the preamble, with the drawback of these characters active only at `\begin{document}`.

Comment: With `babel` 3.9 there's the `KeepShorthandsActive` option, but I wouldn't recommend it for general usage.

Comment: Yes: looks very dangerous! :) I prefer your solution that confines the shorthands deactivation.

Comment: @egreg And with 3.8, in fact. This is one of the oldest options of `babel`.

Comment: @JavierBezos Really? Well, I've always recommended putting `\title` and `\author` after `\begin{document}`. ;-)

Comment: TIL after using LaTeX since the early 1990s that arguments for one command can be consumed by another...