# Use of \NoAutoSpacing inside a macro

Tags: macros, shorthands, active-characters, babel-french

I would like to locally deactivate the colon character (made active by `babel` package used with `frenchb` option). But it appears to not work within a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
In normal text: {\NoAutoSpacing 20:20}. % working

In a macro: \textsuperscript{\NoAutoSpacing 20:20} % not working

\end{document}
```

[image: image result]

This appears to be the same using `\shorthandoff{:}` and `\shorthandon{:}`  (as a consequence, this is linked to [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167594/46718) but I don't clearly see how it applies here.).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It works for me, if by "work", you mean it removes space padding around the `:`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "work", but I'm really surprised you don't have the problem. I'll add a screenshot of the result.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2015. Update your TeX distribution. Or use `20\string:20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue can only be reproduced with TeX Live 2015 or earlier.

If you can't update your TeX distribution, use

```
\textsuperscript{20\string:20}
```

Comment: This indeed solved it (and many other issues, supposedly)!